# how to catch button click event using AngularJs and show an alert box

Tags: angularjs

How can we trigger the button click event using AngularJs and show an alert message box? I have tried the alert("message") messagebox but it doesn't work.

Comment: can this be any help: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/events.html ... just scroll down to AngularJS Event Listener Examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ng-click on button something like this:

**Controller :**

```
   var VLogin = angular.module('myApp',[]);
   VLogin.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {

   $scope.clicked = function(){
        alert("Clicked");
    }
}]);
```

And in your **HTML** like :

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
      <button ng-click="clicked()">Click me!</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the working Fiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/nuejh9h6/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

we need to see what you have wrote but in general this is how ng-click works https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick and you can write your alert code inside or in a new method and call it.